# Hide all Graphs and show them based on ComboBox Selection

Tags: vba, excel, graph, charts

I am fairly new to VBA, and have been searching the forum for one particular code.

I have a workbook with multiple different graphs. I also have a UserForm with a popbox box where the User can select the city and click enter. What I would like to do is Hide all the Worksheets with the graphs, and when the user selects one particular city, I would like Excel to show that particular Graph. For Example, The user Selects Vancouver, and Excel will show the worksheet Pertaining to Vancouver.

I would also Like to Have a done button, where if the user clicks that, it will go back to the sheet where the UserForm is.

```
Private Sub ENT_Click()

'Error if you do not select the City
If Me.City.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a City", vbExclamation, "Select a City"
    Me.City.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Me.City.Value = "Mississauga" Then
Sheets("Sheet4").Visible = True
    Sheets("Sheet4").Activate
End If

End Sub
```

Every time I run the code, with the Worksheets hidden, Or UnHidden, I keep getting a Subscript out of Range error.

Thank you again for the help

Answer (score 0):

It was an error with the way I was labeling my Worksheet. The Code should have actually been:

```
Private Sub ENT_Click()

'Error if you do not select the City
If Me.City.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a City", vbExclamation, "Select a City"
    Me.City.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

'Change "Mississauga" to the item in your ComboBox
If Me.City.Value = "Mississauga" Then 
Worksheets(4).Visible = True
    Worksheets(4).Activate
End If

End Sub
```